# Handle Massive JSON Array FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fullcalendar

I need help in this topic :
I'm using FullCalendar in order to display some tasks in a calendar view. This is a piece of my code :

```
    export default {
  props: {
    _tasks: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
```

```
    _tasks: {
  immediate: true,
  deep: true,
  handler: function () {
    this.setTasks();
  },
},
```

```
      const currentTasks = this._tasks || [];
      this.calendarOptions.events = currentTasks.map(task => {
        const { date, dueDate } = task;
        const startDate = formatDateTime(date);
        const endDate = formatDateTime(dueDate);

        return {
          title: task.title,
          extendedProps: {
            eventId: task.serviceOrderId || task.documentId,
          },
          start: startDate,
          end: endDate || undefined,
          backgroundColor: this.getEventColor(task),
        };
      });
      this.loadRecurrentTasks();
    },
```

But when I send like 3k tasks by props, the callendar become very slow (slow in loading, changing months and opening event dialogs by clicking events, but when load is done, it the vertical scrolling runs pretty well). Any idea of how can I fix it ?

Comment: Question: Why would you try to show 3000 tasks on the calendar at once? No human user can possibly process or understand that quantity of information on the screen at once. It will be overwhelming and make the calendar very hard to understand and use. Obviously I don't know how you've configured the calendar, but consider restricting it to shorter time ranges (e.g. a month at most) and/or adding some filtering so not all the tasks are rendered on the calendar at the same time.

Comment: Or, if these tasks are actually covering a wide time range (e.g. several months), but you are only showing 1 month or 1 week at a time, then consider lazy-loading the events into the calendar, so you only fetch what is actually necessary for the current view, instead of trying to load the entire history at once, even when it might not all be viewed. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function or https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed to read about options for creating such a dynamic event feed.

Comment: @ADyson, I'm doing this rn : I have non-recurrent tasks and recurrent tasks. When my FullCalendar instantiates, I filter the non-recurrent tasks and recurrent tasks to show only in the current month. But my application have cases that users got +2k tasks per month, and I have to handle this case. I completely agree with you: it is kinda hard to understand, idk, 2k tasks in a month, but I have to show it lol.

Comment: Can you do what I suggested then, and only show them in a weekly view? Also you didn't mention...what version of fullCalendar are you using? The newest ones have some performance improvements over older editions.

Comment: @ADyson, my team asked for monthly view :/ And i'm using v6. Idk for real how to improve this situation...

Comment: Ok. At the end of the day though, your options are still the ones I mentioned in my first comments. People can't always get exactly what they asked for (and often, what they asked for isn't actually the best outcome either)! You have to find a sensible way to reduce the potential number of events to a realistic one which a) the system can cope with and b) a human being can cope with. My first step would be to have a discussion with your team about what a good user experience looks like.

Comment: I find it a valid question how to display thousands of items, and it can probably be done, just not easily. I don't know FullCalendar, but either there are config options, or that package is just not capable of handling that amount of items. It is sometimes necessary to find another package, or develop a custom solution, if you have special requirements.

Comment: @kca I know the package fairly well (although I'm not involved in its development directly). The options are as I mentioned in the first comments. It is not really designed to display that number of events simultaneously, because it was assumed nobody would ever be daft enough to do so, because the UX would be awful, regardless of any performance considerations. So yeah, there's not much can be done within the fullCalendar options. The solutions - both for the technical and user experience issue - is to find ways to reduce the number of events on display simultaneously.

Comment: Didn't want to blame FullCalendar. A package has it's use case, and this isn't it. E.g. you wouldn't use React.js for high frequency trading. But I find it legitimate to have the need to display lots of items. There are apps that can display infinitely many items, just not all of them visible in the viewport at the same time. I've written a serious app that displayed 10.000 items on one screen, each few pixels in size, but zoomable and clickable, to get an overview about the general amount of existing data.

Comment: @kca that's fine, but that isn't what's being asked here. And such a question would actually be quite broad for SO anyway.